# Selenium Edge Driver and File Input Type

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I call the `.getAttribute("value")` method on an `input` element with `type="file"` to get the uploaded filename but it doesn't work. I get an empty string. This works with all other browsers but not Edge. Is this a known Edge bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
WebElement fileDialog = driver.findElement(By.id("fileDialogID"));
String uploadedFilename = fileDialog.getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: Have you waited for the file to be uploaded? Maybe with Edge the upload is slower than other browsers and when you try to get the name, the file is still not uploaded yet

Comment: @marco Yes, I waited. Did it worked for you?

Comment: never worked with selenium on Edge, usually in Chrome this works fine, maybe you can try to use `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement` to wait for the name of the file to be present in the element

Comment: @marco I suspect this is a Selenium Edge driver bug.